# Open and Read an Excel file in UWP application

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, mobile, uwp

I'm starting to learn application development trying to implement an application in UWP (Universal Windows Platform) that opens an Excel file to show its data to the user, since I have an idea that would require this feature.

However, following a WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) tutorial to do the same thing I've run into an exception when I try to open the Excel application through code, probably due to some devices on the UWP set not supporting Excel (?).

I'm wondering if there is some way of fixing this problem by specifying that my application will be deployed only to a PC device or a tablet. If there is no way of doing this, UWP is a bad option to create programs that deal with Excel files at the moment?

Should I migrate to WPF, or is there another solution in UWP?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How is the WPF app doing it? Using the Office interop APIs? Here is a post describing how you can use the APIs from a UWP on desktop: https://stefanwick.com/2017/05/26/uwp-calling-office-interop-apis/

Comment: Please share the code you have so far. See how to create a [mcve] as well as "[ask]". Questions asking for opinion are not on-topic here (especially when they don't include problematic code or anything else that could help others in the future.)   See the **[help/on-topic]** for more information about what's on-topic on this site

Comment: Just a tip, you can also use the Open XML SDK to work with Office items : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk ( I used it once to create excel files on the fly with xamarin http://depblog.weblogs.us/2017/10/13/net-standard-2-0-create-microsoft-office-documents-in-xamarin-forms/ )

Comment: epplus is also great for working with Excel - https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Comment: @ashleedawg  Sorry, I'm not with my computer right now, but my code is pretty much the same from here: [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/read-excel-file-in-c-sharp-winform/] , and by commenting specific parts I found out that the problem ocurred whenever the line below was called.

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();`

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT thanks! This looks like a solution for my problem, do you know if this would work if I tried to build for tablets or phones? I'm not really familiar with UWP yet.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I will take a look at the given options, but is nice to know I have more alternatives to dealing with excel files, I will try it out and see which one best fits my needs.

Comment: @Tonon it would work on PCs and Tablets (i.e. devices that run the desktop version of Windows 10). Not on phones or HoloLens.

Answer (score 1):

You should not switch to WPF. You should forget about interop and use [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK).

Disadvantages of interop:

- Slow, since it uses COM objects;
- Works only on windows;
- Requires excel to be installed on the PC;
- Largely depends on excel and if excel app fails you will have problems. And it's not excel problem anymore, but your own problem. And you will have to deal with your customer's issues since your app cannot work properly because of broken excel.

Advantages of OpenXML sdk:

- Fast, since it works directly with xlsx file;
- Works on UWP, WPF, Winforms, Mono, .net Core, Xamarin Mac, Xamarin android, xamarin ios;
- Does not require Excel app to be installed;
- Has nice reverse engineering tool ([Open XML SDK Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)) which allows to turn any xlsx into C#.

OpenXML sdk documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

You can use EPPlus package which support UWP 
[Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). It is super Excel spreadsheet helper for UWP Application