# Read .xlsx file as if it was a .csv file during execution

Tags: c#, excel, csv, uwp

I have some code that read CSV data from `.csv` files.

The problem is that if I only have some `.xlsx` files in a folder I can't read them (don't want to use third-party library I prefer to read CSV files).

So what I want to do is to read the data from the `.xlsx` files as if they were `.csv` files, is there any way to perform that ?

Comment: If they are CSV files... save them as CSV files. And unless you want to get into some very complex decompression and XML parsing, you will need a third-party library to convert XLSX to CSV.

Comment: They aren't CSV files, they're actually XLSX. 
For the third-party library I was talking about reading the XLSX directly not about the conversion. The few libraries that I saw about converting XLSX to CSV were only able to convert the files and save them at the same location, but no "on the fly" conversion to read it during execution.

Comment: Why do you need a CSV file? Use a library like EPPlus and just read the data from the sheets into your data objects, then process the data objects.

Comment: The files have 10k+ rows, the only library that I used were so slow. But I will try EPPlus.

Comment: Does the Excel Interop not work for you?

Comment: I saw here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085479/open-and-read-an-excel-file-in-uwp-application) that interop was slow whereas I want my program to seek values very fast.

Comment: I've used this package `EPPlus.DataExtractor`. It's built on EPPlus and simplifies reading collections from files the same way CsvHelper does. Converting EPPlus to CSV would just be an extra step.

Comment: I think that could be what I need, thanks !

Comment: @ScottHannen, You comments are correct, could you post as the answer for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

you can just perform a basic test to see what's the type of your file and in case it's not CSV convert it to CSV (given it's XLSX):

```
wbWorkbook.SaveAs("c:\YOURFILE.csv", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV)
```